# Implementing windows authentication in MVC using Active Directory (AD)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, active-directory, windows-authentication

I have following requirement for my application :

- Application Security will be controlled with Windows integrated
  security.  The Active Directory (AD) Domain must be stored in the application XML
  configuration file.
- Users will be able to View the Master File and Transaction
  assignments with no security.
- There will be one AD group for Adding / Changing / Deleting Master
  File data.
- There will be one AD group for assigning Master File data to
  Transaction data.
- A user could be in one, both or neither of the groups. The AD groups 
  will be stored in the application XML configuration file.

I understood the requirement but not sure how to implement it.
Specially the part 'A user could be in one, both or neither of the groups.'

Any thoughts or directions would be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know all solutions, but hope this will try to help you

For Point1 :- for windows security use windows authentication and check the identity of the user, and make your database related to users stored in separate XML file and read the data(user information) from XML file.

For point2 :- Add the user AD which are going to access the system(on IIS machine)and create group for View/edit/assign permission set appropriate role as per your need, and use this group in while doing login

For point3-4: create separate login to access the file data and transcation data.

Comment: Hi, I was able to create groups and users on my server. Any idea how can i validate them in my application ?

Comment: in MVC use authorize filter to validate user and specify role name- google it for the filter

Comment: Ok like this [Authorize(Roles = @"Domain\\Role")] ?

Comment: Yessss, This worked... Thanks man. I will check for 'user in multiple roles' now..